# Ruby/Rails using || to determine value, using an empty string instead of a nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I usually do

```
 value = input || "default"
```

so if input = nil

```
 value = "default"
```

But how can I do this so instead of `nil` It also counts an empty string `''` as `nil`

I want so that if I do

```
input = ''
value = input || "default"
=> "default"
```

Is there a simple elegant way to do this without `if`?

Comment: Note that you tagged your question as `ruby-on-rails`, hence the Rails specific answers.

Comment: Yes I was running on rails so its no problem, I also tagged ruby because it looked more of a ruby problem-edited the title to match answers/question better

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Rails adds [presence](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) method to all object that does exactly what you want

```
input = ''
value = input.presence || "default"
=> "default"

input = 'value'
value = input.presence || "default"
=> "value"

input = nil
value = input.presence || "default"
=> "default"
```

Comment: Yep, but it's _RAILS_ONLY_, 'pure' ruby does not have it.

Comment: Yes, it's Rails extension, as well as `blank?`

Answer (score 6):

I usually do in this way:

```
value = input.blank? ? "default" : input
```

In response to the case that input might not be defined, you may guard it by:

```
value = input || (input.blank? ? "default" : input)
# I just tried that the parentheses are required, or else its return is incorrect
```

For pure ruby (not depending on Rails), you may use `empty?` like this:

```
value = input || (input.empty? ? "default" : input)
```

or like this *(thanks @substantial for providing this)*:

```
value = (input ||= "").empty? ? "default" : input
```

Comment: I have another question -- it works great if we have input actually defined somewhere. But what if we don't? So, all we get is 'undefined local variable or method' ?

Comment: @DmitriyUgnichenko updated the answer, see if it answer you question :)

Comment: @PeterWong Nope, it didn't. Still having `undefined input`.

Comment: @DmitriyUgnichenko `value = (input ||= "").blank? ? "default" : input` This will set `input` to an empty string if undefined.

Comment: @gg_s Yep, thanks, it works. But is there the same solution, but not Rails specific? (pure Ruby)?

Comment: Yeah, extend the core `Object` class to include `blank?` [just like Rails does](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a371368c91789a4d689d6a84eb20b238c37678a/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L15). Ask a new question if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe irrelavant but I would use highline like this:

```
require "highline/import"

input = ask('Input: ') { |q| q.default = "default" }
```

It works without Rails. Really neat solution.