# Best practice for empty table columns in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a question about database data in Rails.

What is the best practice for empty table columns?

I don't have defaults on some columns that aren't compulsory for user input eg.

```
User model
ID | name       | drink_of_choice |  favourite_color
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | Benji      | coffee          |  yellow
2  | Becky      | tea             |  NULL
-----------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see Becky's favouritte_color is NULL because Becky didn't enter her favourite color yet.

Do Rails developers set :default => '' as a best practice to save an empty string and avoid NULL in the database?

Thank you for your patience and I appreciate any advice to further my learning.

WD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many options...

1- The first one is to force the user to enter some data. So, you can use [validation of presence](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#presence):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :drink_of_choice, :favourite_color, :presence => true
  ...
end
```

2- However, you might want to allow users to leave some columns empty. If so, you can set a default value for it in your model, for example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_favourite_color
  ...
  def set_favourite_color
    self.favourite_color ||= ''
  end
end
```

3- You could also set it in your controller, such as:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.favourite_color ||= ''
  ...
end
```

4- Another option, but I don't really like it (not flexible at all), is defining it in your migration file:

```
class CreateUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ...
      t.string :favourite_color, default: ''
      ...
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

What is the best approach?

Following the Rails Best Practices, more precisely: Fat Model, Skinny Controller. I would choose the option 2.

**EDIT** - Before deciding about a default value for the column, think about the meaning of it. If the meaning is no data entered, I think you should leave it as null. Thanks to [Daniel Rikowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23368/daniel-rikowski)'s comment, please take a look [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638291/standard-use-of-z-instead-of-null-to-represent-missing-data).

Comment: +1 I agree with your overall opinion ("many options") but I think writing the string `empty` is not a good idea. Denoting an empty/unset/unitialized field is exactly the purpose of a NULL value. Also one could argue that a surrogate value belongs in the view, like `<%= user.favourite_color || "empty"`. See this question and its answers for a similar proposal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638291/standard-use-of-z-instead-of-null-to-represent-missing-data

Comment: Thank you Gabriel and Daniel for the insight and getting me to think about options and the meaning of the data. As the data isn't integral, I've opted for the view option. I appreciate your help, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this gem if it works for you :

https://github.com/rubiety/nilify_blanks

This also can help u-> [Ruby/Rails using || to determine value, using an empty string instead of a nil value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415357/ruby-rails-using-to-determine-value-using-an-empty-string-instead-of-a-nil-v)

Comment: Thanks Rathore. Appreciate the link to the gem and more importantly showing me the presence method.

Comment: Well, urs Welcome... Happy to help U. @WasabiDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

On Rails views, I use something like this:

```
<%= input unless input.blank? %>
```

And leave the data as is on the DB.